# How to remove duplicates depending on values in another column(s)?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

```
[Week]           [User]

Week 1           Bryan
Week 1           Sam
Week 1           Bryan
Week 1           Will
Week 2           Bryan
Week 2           Will
Week 2           Will
```

I'm looking to be able to count unique users per week.  Therefore, I'd like to remove duplicates, but per week.  So in the example above, Week 1 should only have Bryan, Sam, and Will, and Week 2 will have Bryan, and Will.
Regular "Remove Duplicates" will remove names across weeks as well which is what I don't want.  So is there someway to count and/or remove duplicates in a column, based on value(s) in another column?  VBA code is also very much welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert Pivot Table.
In a Rows put [Week] and below that put [User]

It would automatically give you list of weeks and users (only once).

Comment: Still new to pivot tables. I didn't realize putting it under rows will give me unique values. That's perfect, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large data set and you want to accomplish this in VBA, you can achieve this by using the RemoveDuplicates method.

Try this:

```
Dim LR as Long 

LR = activesheet.usedrange.rows.count

Range(“A1:B” & LR).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  ***Remove Duplicates*** to achieve what you described in your post.

Select your range, and then select both columns, click the check mark **V** next to "My data has headers":

[image]

Result after running:

[image]